# Can I have individual Software Restriction Policies in Windows for individual users?

Tags: windows, group-policy

Using software restriction policies in Windows I can prevent users from starting unwanted software. My question is, can I have different groups of users with different rules?

I would like to have one "standard" group that can start all programs in `C:\Windows` and `C:\Programs` (and other directories), and a second "guest" group that is only allowed to start very few programs. However, so far I have only found ways to implement one rule set.

Currently I use the [c't tool Restric'tor](https://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/Restric-tor-Profi-Schutz-fuer-jedes-Windows-3690890.html) which seems to be uncapable of this. Also, the [Microsoft site I've found](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh994606(v=ws.11)) does not provide any information on this. I use Windows 10 Professional. Thanks for any help.

Comment: "My question is, can I have different groups of users with different rules?"  - Yes.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. How do I achieve this? Is there a tutorial somewhere? I haven't found one.

Comment: You can apply group policies to specific machines, specific groups of machines, specific user groups, even apply the policy to a single user.  It is much easier to do all that if you have an AD Domain though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario**

You want to prevent all Sales Dept. employees installing software, opening portable apps and PowerShell but not rest of the company.

**Guide**

1. Create an OU structure in AD, for example: company.com > users > sales
2. Add your users into that OU
3. Within Group Policy Management, expand your OU, company.com > users > sales and right click the sales folder and select ¨Create a GPI in this domain, and Link it here...¨
4. Now right click the new Policy you´ve just created and ´Edit..´ it.
5. Be sure to create the policy under User Configuration and NOT Computer Configuration (User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Software Restriction Policies)

**Example Policy**

```
Enforcement > All users except local administrators

Designated File Types > Remove: LNK

Designated File Types > Add: PSH, PS1, PSM1, PSD1, APPX, AppxBundle, WSF, FNT, FON, OTF, TTF, PS, GADGET, CAB

Security Levels > Disallowed
```

**Additional Rules:**

Unrestricted (Very Important)

```
%HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRoot%
%HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir (x86)%
%HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir%
```

Other Unrestricted

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Mozilla Thunderbird
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Opera
```

Restricted*

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell
```

*Do not use environment variables in restrictions, bypasses are possible